# what to set in Capybara.app for a Middleman project?

Tags: capybara, middleman

In the env.rb to use Capybara you should setup Capybara.app = something
Middleman is based on sinatra so I was thinking to use Sinatra::Application but gives an error

Anyone know what should be put to set up Capybara in the proper way?

Answer (score 2):

Although I've recently stated this answer in the (recently closed) GitHub issue that @bhollis gave, I should fill in the answer here as well in keeping with the spirit of StackOverflow.

In a `spec_helper.rb` file added to a `spec` folder in the root of your Middleman project, the assignment I've used is `Capybara.app = Middleman::Application.server.inst` - however, I configure it a little bit too like so:

```
Capybara.app = Middleman::Application.server.inst do
  set :root, File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..'))
  set :environment, :development
  set :show_exceptions, false
end
```

A full example of this using RSpec can be found [here](https://github.com/simonrice/middleman-rspec).

Answer (score 0):

The answer will eventually be at https://github.com/middleman/middleman/issues/895